# set end date as selected start date in bootstrap material datepicker

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm building a solution which will contain the ability to select the start date and end date of an event, having two input fields one for start date and other for end date using bootstrap **material datetimepicker**, the issue is that when selecting a start date, and directly submitting the form, end date will automatically take the value of start date.

I have tried something like:

```
if( $("#end_date").val() == null || $("#end_date").val() == "" ){
   eventObj["end_date"] = "'" + $("#start_date").val() + "'";
}
```

Can anyone help please ?

Answer (score 0):

`if( $("#end_date").val() == null || $("#end_date").val() == "" ){
   eventObj["end_date"] = "'" + $("#start_date").val() + "'";
}` like this I have tried

when i using boostrap datepicker and using the change event to called the datepicker and you can use the any function for the date picker

when selecting a start date, and directly click submitting the form , then you can take the end date value in that function

check this example

https://jsfiddle.net/0Ltv25o8/4677/

Comment: thanks, I just made something similar, when choosing a start date, the end date will be automatically generated and equals the start date, and set it's minDate equals the startDate. 
Thank you.